# Typescript Template Literals erroring with TS7053 when executing

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I'm attempting to use template literals to dynamically select colors from a theme object. The simplified version would look something like this:

```
type Colors = {
  red: string;
  blue: string;
  redLight: string;
  blueLight: string;
};

const colors: Colors = {
  red: 'a',
  blue: 'b',
  redLight: 'c',
  blueLight: 'd'
};

type BaseColors= 'red' | 'blue';

const getLightColor = (val: BaseColors) => {
  return colors[`${val}Light`];
};
```

The template literals work fine in my IDE and I get no warnings at all, but when running the project I get the following error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Colors'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Colors'.
    63 |
    64 | const getLightColor = (val: BaseColors) => {
  > 65 |   return colors[`${val}Light`];
       |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    66 | };
    67 |
```

I'm running Typescript v 4.3.5 and I haven't been able to find any references online for this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: `type BaseColors = 'red' | 'blue'`

Comment: Updated the `BaseColors`. That was a typo when trying to simplify the example.

Answer (score 0):

New answer (after more explanations):

You just need simple fix in your getLightColor function to indicate that the key you provide is a key of Colors type so it can be safely used here:

```
const getLightColor = (val: BaseColors) => {
  return colors[`${val}Light` as keyof Colors];
};
```

---

Old answer (before fixed code in first post and comment explaining the issue in details):

You have mixed two things and I'm not sure which direction you need but there are two options here:

1. You want to get value from `colors` using key of type `BaseColors`.
   In this case your `BaseColors` need to match key names of `colors` so it can be `type BaseColors = 'red' | 'blue'` instead of `type BaseColors = 'a' | 'b'` because you can get colors using `colors['red']` or `colors['blue']` (and not `colors['a']` or `colors['b']`).
2. You want to get key names by value (reverse mapping).
   In this case you need custom function to find key by value in `colors`. You can define the function like this:

```
type BaseColors = 'a' | 'b';

function findColorNameByValue(val: BaseColors): string {
  return Object.keys(colors).filter(name => colors[name] === val)[0];
}
```

(or more general `val` parameter in the function can be defined as `string` because it can accept also other values but it's up to you)

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Thee was an error in the `BaseColors` when I copied and simplified the object structure. The issue is still the same, it happens when trying to obtain `colors['redLight']`.

Comment: Bernat, I updated my answer and provided you fix for this issue. Basically you just need to use `as keyof` to indicate that your string is a key of Colors type.

If this solved your issue - please mark my answer as accepted, otherwise - let me know so I will try to help you.

Comment: Hi Pawel, Thanks for your help. I already found that, but it's basically just making typescript shut up. You could be returning `colors['bananas' as keyof Colors]` and typescript still wouldn't complain. This is getting rid of the type-safety instead of fixing the issue. As I mentioned, the original code is not causing an error (and typescript knows which values are acceptable. For example, `colors[${val}Light]` is OK but  `colors[${val}Dark]` will fail). Yet, the code breaks when executing.

Comment: Bernat, so the code is working well (tried it by myself as well and it seems to be working fine). You had the error you mentioned just because TS didn't know this value is ok so it was proper fix for the issue. As far as I understand you - it works OK also for you when you use `colors[${val}Light]` right? `${val}Dark` doesn't exist in colors so when you do `colors[${val}Dark]` it's returning `undefined` so make sure you're either providing only existing keys (e.g. you extend colors with dark colors) or check if value is not undefined. What is the error now and what behaviour is expected?